# CriteriaBuilder, how to create a subquery?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, java-6

I'm trying to create a subquery using `CriteriaBuilder` but don't know how to manage to do so.

The subquery I want to create is the following

`WHERE number IN (SELECT otherNumber FROM table WHERE otherNnumber IS NOT NULL)`

I have tried using `CriteriaBuilder#in` but couldn't understand how the method works and what it does + the javadoc is not super clear about that

Comment: `CriteriaBuilder.subquery` creates the subquery ... and you use that subquery as input to other methods

Comment: @NeilStockton Does it exist? I can't find it

Comment: Sorry, `CriteriaQuery.subquery`

Comment: @NeilStockton Yes thanks I've found it now.